# Save a list of objects in model as a field

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to write internet-shop, and I have a model `Order`:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    state_choices = ('ACTIVE', 'COMPLETED', 'FROZEN')
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_street = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_building = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='ACTIVE')
    products = models.ForeignKey(OrderProduct)
    client = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
```

And `OrderProduct`:

```
class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    product_ammount = models.IntegerField()
```

As you can see, user can add to order different products and different ammount of each product. So, with current models, I can add to order only one type of product. Then I rewrite it in the next way:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    state_choices = ('ACTIVE', 'COMPLETED', 'FROZEN')
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_street = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_building = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='ACTIVE')
    client = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    product_ammount = models.IntegerField()
```

And in a `view`, when I need to get a user's orders, I just do next: `Order.objects.get(client=request.user).orderproduct_set`
But I think that it's not correct. How to rebuild these models to gain the desired result?

Comment: @sthzg, where to save number of product? As I understand, with `ManyToMany`, i don't need `OrderProduct` model. So How to save ammount of one `product` in `order`? Or should I use `ManyToMany` in `OrderProduct` for `order` field?

Comment: Sorry, on second thought this is correct. A `manytomany` is possible, but it's not an elegant solution (since an instance of `OrderProduct` can only be related to one `Order`.

Comment: One small problem with the second approach is that the query uses `get()` instead of `filter()`. This might lead to an exception once one user has more than one order. Otherwise it seems fine.

Comment: @sthzg, so why have you deleted your answer? Is it not correct?

Comment: It would work but is wrong by design. A `ManyToMany` relation would read like this: a) one `Order` can be related to multiple `OrderProduct` **AND** b) one `OrderProduct` can be related to multiple `Order`. a) is correct, but b) is not. One `OrderProduct` can only ever belong to one `Order` instance. This is why in my opinion your second approach is a better design.

Comment: @sthzg, okay, thank you. But maybe there is other solution for my problem, except for these two my approaches?

Comment: @sthzg, but when I use `Order.objects.filter(client=request.user).orderproduct_set.all()`, it throws an error. `orderproduct_set` can be used only with `get`?

Comment: Filter will return a `QuerySet` and not a single instance, to access the first item you could do `Order.objects.filter(client=request.user)[0].orderproduct_set.all()`. Or you could loop over all results with a for loop.

Comment: @sthzg, can I just pass `order` instance to template, and in template get products of the order? Or I just have to get `products` of the `order` in a view, and pass it to template?

Comment: I added a bit of information on how to use it in a template in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the second approach is perfectly fine.

One small error in the question is that the query uses `get()` instead of `filter()`. This will lead to an exception once one user has more than one order.

So, instead of the `get()` it would be:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(client=request.user)
for order in orders:
    print order.orderproduct_set.all()
```

To use this in a template (question from the comments) it is enough to pass the orders:

**views.py**

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
         ctx = {
             'orders': Order.objects.filter(client=request.user)
         }
         return render(request, 'my/template.html', ctx)
```

**my/template.html**

```
{% for order in orders %}
    {% for item in order.orderproduct_set.all %}
        {{ item.product_amount }}x {{ item.product }}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```